# How to insert multiple form in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with input multiple form, in my case, result array is like this

```
{
approval_activities": null,
  "remark_id": [
    "9",
    "10"
  ],
  "name_remark": [
    "Capex",
    "Asset"
  ],
  "label_remark": [
    "Capex",
    "Asset"
  ],
  "description_remark": [
    "Capex",
    "Asset"
  ],
  "filter_logic_remark": [
    null,
    null
  ],
  "default_remark": [
    "Capex",
    "Asset"
  ],
  "weight_remark": [
    "5",
    "1"
  ]
```

I try to insert it to other table using foreach, but I have error message Array to string conversion

$asset = Asset::create([,'approval_activities' => $request->approval_activities]);
$arr[] = $request->all();

```
      foreach ($arras $req) { //remark
        $i = 0;
        $pret = [
          'asset_id'        => $asset->id,
          'remark_id'       => $req[$i]['remark_id'],
          'name'            => $req[$i]['name_remark'],
          'label'           => $req[$i]['label_remark'],
          'description'     => $req[$i]['description_remark'],
          'filter_logic'    => $req[$i]['filter_logic_remark'],
          'default'         => $req[$i]['weight_remark']
        ];
        $i++;
      }
      RemarkAsset::create($pret);
```

this is my form in blade, in this code I use `[]` in name for send an array to controller, the result from this code is like JSON above.

```
{!! Form::label('approval_activities', 'Approval Jenis Kegiatan', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-sm-4 {{ $errors->has('approval_activities') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
<select id="approval_activities" name="approval_activities" class="form-control select2_demo_1"
data-placeholder="Select Approval Jenis Kegiatan">
<option value="">Select Approval Jenis Kegiatan</option>
<option value="Aktivasi">Aktivasi</option>
</select> {!! $errors->first('approval_kegiatan', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::text('name_remark[]', $item->name, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::label('label', 'Label', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label f-w-none']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 {{ $errors->has('label') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::text('label_remark[]', $item->name, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Label']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('label', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    </div>
```

My expect is inserting `$asset` to table asset just have 1 record, and the remark is inserted to table remark, if I have two remark_id or other like JSON above then the record in table remark is two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$req[$i]['name_remark']` would work if the array looked like the following, where there is a `name_remark` for every `$i`.

```
{
    "name_remark": "Capex"
},
{
    "name_remark": "Asset"
}
```

In your case I believe you want `$req['name_remark'][$i]` instead.